# Python Section Sort does not function as it is told to do so

Tags: python

If I input a single digit number or numbers with the same first digit (10, 11, 12, 13), the code works perfectly. However, as soon as this condition is not met, the program thinks 7 is larger than 12...

Here is what I have tried.

```
def main():
mark = 0
file_name = input('Enter the name of the file: ')
lst = []
for num in open(file_name):
    lst.append(num.strip())
print(lst)
lst = sort(lst, mark)
print(lst)


def sort(lst, mark):
while mark <= len(lst) - 1:
    minval = lst[mark]
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i] > minval:
            lst[i], lst[mark] = lst[mark], lst[i]
    minval = lst[mark]
    mark += 1
    sort(lst, mark)
return lst

main()
```

Comment: you are comparing strings. String "7" is *larger* than "12" (it is compared alphabetically).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're sorting the numbers as strings instead of as integers. In fact, the string "7" is larger than the string "12" in the same way that the string "g" would come after the string "ab" in the dictionary.

You can avoid this by casting your inputs to ints:

```
num = int(input_string)
```